# Run PHP script at a certain ( dynamic ) time ? Alternatives to cronjob

Tags: php, cron

I'm working on a service where the user schedules his tweets so for example i want to post a tweet tomorrow at 12:30 PM. How can that be done ? is cron jobs the best way to do so ? like running a cronjob every 5 minutes and see if there are tweets to post in this interval ? Are there any alternatives ?

Comment: You can use cron jobs the other alternative is set a scheduler job to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running a cron job is definitely the easiest solution, however there are other approaches available, one such approach would be to use a queue like [Amazons SQS](http://aws.amazon.com/sqs/)

This lets you simply throw things onto a queue to be processed later, by default they are immediately added to the queue in a state ready to be processed immediately, however you can add items to the queue with a timestamp they should remain dormant until. This would be your users predefined tweet time.

You could then have a script running that is constantly listening to the queue for any new tweets that need to be sent, as soon as a queue item becomes available, it will be processed.

The downside to this is of course that it's more effort, the upsides though are that you can scale easier since you can have multiple machines processing tweets and they wont ever send out the same tweet twice (whereas if two machines are running the same cron, there's the chance they'll both send out the tweet)